# Converting NSFetchRequest data to dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have

```
let param: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [
      "customer_id":user_id!,
      "customer_name":customer_name!,
      "customer_phone":customer_phone!,
      "total": 3223, 
      "delivery_fee": 200, 
      "restaurant_id": restu_id[i], 
      "card_id": card_id!,
      "customer_address_id": 20,
      "customer_street_address": customer_address!, 
      "customer_address_coordinates": customer_coordinate!, 
      "Order_details": vrt]
```

The problem now is my `vrt` is also of type `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`
How can I add it to `param`.

Comment: You say you want a dictionary, but the "how you want the data to appear" section shows an array of dictionaries, not a dictionary.

Comment: @picciano Yea i edited the question

Comment: Did you try <String: Any> instead of <String:AnyObject> as type for param?  A Dictionary is a value type so I don't it'll work with AnyObject

Comment: Yes but Alamofire does not conform to <String:Any> it conforms to <String:AnyObject>